# getSharedPreferences not working for me with concerns to ListPreferences and Integers

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, integer, listpreference

I'm stuck at a point where I'm trying to get my project to read a preference value (from a ListPreference listing) and then use that value in a basic mathematical subtraction instance.  The problem is that the "seek" preference is not being seen by my Java code, and yet the default value is (I've tried the default value with 3000 and now 0).  Am i missing something, is there a bug here, known or unknown?

Here is my Java code chunk where the issues manifests itself:

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "preferences";
seekback.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
try {  
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
 Integer storedPreference = preferences.getInt("seek", 0);

(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()-storedPreference);

} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
});
```

Here are some other code bits for my project:

From preferences file:

```
 <ListPreference
 android:entries="@array/seconds"
 android:entryValues="@array/seconds_values"
 android:summary="sets the seek interval for the seekback and seekforward buttons"
 android:title="Seek Interval"
 android:defaultValue="5000"
 android:key="@string/seek">
 </ListPreference>
```

From strings file:

```
<string name="seek">seek</string>
```

From an array file:

```
<resources>
    <string-array
      name="seconds">
      <item>Five seconds</item>
      <item>Fifteen seconds</item>
      <item>Thirty seconds</item>
      <item>Sixty seconds</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array
      name="seconds_values">
      <item>5000</item>
      <item>15000</item>
      <item>30000</item>
      <item>60000</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

*let me know if you need to see more code to figure this one out*

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered.  I've worked over this issue now for a few hours and I'm burnt, a second pair of eyes on it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue.  It turns out that my project was named with an "_" character and once I refactored the underscore out (and used the getDefaultSharedPreferences option), all is working as should be.

This issue absorbed 30 hours of my time!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you store the ListPreference values in the same files.
Start up `adb` roll to the `cd /data/data/com.your.package` and look for folders and files of type preferences.

I think the bug is that you specify a different file than the one the setting has been saved too:

Try changing this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, please bare with me. I've changed out to SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreference(getBaseContext()); However, I'm debugging directly on a phone. I see the path to my project, but it's at F:\data\com.mypackage and all I see is the one file that should be writing to that directory (which works fine, both reading and writing to it). Ps. I mounted my phone's SD, whould that give me an accurate path view or do I need to go the adb route as you noted here? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You are doing fine, check the pref file and open in an editor, and check out if the key exists and holds the correct value.

Comment: It looks like the value serialized out properly.  I opened it in EditPlus 3 and see android:key="@string/seek".  It's also in the res/xml directory.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that when I first started this project I created preferences.xml and Preferences.java (note the upper-case "P" character).  Would this be an issue?  I do not see any design-time errors thrown, nor at runtime.

Comment: Oh, I was just reading back on your question. The file being written is another file (.3gpp). I do not see any other files in my project directory on the phone. Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: Well certainly you are doing something wrong, or your settings are not saved, so the file doesn't exists yet. For my application the .XML file is at  `/data/data/com.myapp/shared_prefs/com.myapp_preferences.xml` You need to figure out to get some files in `shared_prefs` folder.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try a sample project from scratch. This is odd for sure.

Comment: Just run the examples from the ApiDemos (check your android install folder for samples /platforms/.../samples

Comment: okay.  I'll still beating my head, let me give the ApiDemos a twirl.  Thanks again for your patience, help.